# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I have developed this web-based application on a wamp server and it runs ok, and now I started creating a desktop application using electron from last week and I keep on getting this error. But I can login and it works fine, except for the errors I get. Guys, please help me out on this one, this is my first-week using electron.

**Below are all the links and scripts loaded**

```
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
   folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
<!-- Morris chart -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/morris.js/morris.css">
<!-- jvectormap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<!-- Daterange picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">

<!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**For footer**

```
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<!-- <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<!-- FLOT CHARTS -->
<script src="bower_components/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<!-- FLOT RESIZE PLUGIN - allows the chart to redraw when the window is resized -->
<script src="bower_components/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<!-- Page script -->
```

Comment: can you give code and not only `script` tags also the error trace would be helpful.Thanks in advance

Comment: fixed grammar misktakes

Answer (score 0):

Try including JQuery

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It still throws the same error, i have tried placing jQuery at top and at the bottom

Comment: Can you share the line of code where you are getting the error?

Comment: It appears on multiple code lines
        

`// Wait for window load
        $(window).on('load',function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        });

$(document).ready(function(){
                  setInterval(function(){
                    $('#Bookings').load('booking-data.php');
                  },1500);
                });
`